# Building Boost with minGW

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, mingw, codeblocks

I use CodeBlocks(minGW) and I'm having problems with building boost. "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin" is in the Path variable and I was able to build b2 and bjam with "bootstrap.bat gcc" but after "b2 toolset=gcc --build-type=complete" I get some errors.

output:

```
link.jam: No such file or directory

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : yes
    - arm                      : no
    - mips1                    : no
    - power                    : no
    - sparc                    : no
    - x86                      : yes
    - has_icu builds           : no
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : no
    - iconv (libc)             : no
    - iconv (separate)         : no
    - icu                      : no
    - icu (lib64)              : no
    - g++ -shared-* supported  : yes
    - message-compiler         : no
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : yes
    - gcc visibility           : yes
    - long double support      : yes
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
warning: No python installation configured and autoconfiguration
note: failed.  See http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html
note: for configuration instructions or pass --without-python to
note: suppress this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
    - zlib                     : no  (cached)
C:/libs/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/build\virtual-target.jam:1099: in virtual-target.register-actual-name from module virtual-target
error: Duplicate name of actual target: libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_55.a
error: previous virtual target { common%common.copy-libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_55.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.archive-libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_55.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.compile.c++-clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.o.OBJ { clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.cpp.CPP } } } }
error: created from ./stage-proper
error: another virtual target { common%common.copy-libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_55.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.archive-libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_55.a.STATIC_LIB { gcc%gcc.compile.c++-clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.o.OBJ { clone_current_exception_non_intrusive.cpp.CPP } } } }
error: created from ./stage-proper
error: added properties: -shared-libgcc -shared-libstdc++
error: removed properties: none
C:/libs/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/build\virtual-target.jam:484: in actualize-no-scanner from module object(file-target)@5267
C:/libs/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/build\virtual-target.jam:134: in class@virtual-target.actualize from module object(file-target)@5267
C:/libs/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:720: in load from module build-system
C:\libs\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:289: in import from module modules
C:\libs\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
C:\libs\boost_1_55_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

Comment: At a first glance you seem to miss having an appropriate python installation in your build environment (which is a prerequisite for boost's build mechanism). Did you bootstrap the installation properly?

Comment: I guess. I used "bootstrap.bat gcc".

Comment: And you had the MinGw GCC available with your `%PATH%` variable at this point I'd guess?!? I'm not so sure what is necessary to solve the missing python dependency and if it's really a prerequisite or should be automatically installed during boost build & install.

Comment: Yes but I just tried "b2 toolset=gcc" instead of "b2 toolset=gcc --build-type=complete" and it continues building. (I don't know if I got the error again)

Comment: Now Code::Blocks can't find boost::system::... I followed step 7 and 8 here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/58820. If I add "lboost_system" it can't be found.

Comment: Add a library path using the -L option. Lookup the boost build directory for the stage directory, the libs are there usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This was answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I tried `b2 toolset=gcc` and it works.
>   I got the Error "undefined reference to boost::system::.." when I tried to use boost::threads and solved it with linking:

```
boost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_55
boost_system-mgw47-mt-1_55
```